# "Einfachheitshalber" vs. "der Einfachheit halber"

Tags: word-choice, adverb, adverbial

What is the difference? When only one of *einfachheitshalber* and *der Einfachheit halber* fits?

Answer (score 2):

The word **einfachheitshalber** is an adverb made from the preposition *halber* (meaning: *because of*) and the noun *die Einfachheit*. There are some more common adverbs of that sort:

> vorsichtshalber
>
> beispielshalber
>
> umständehalber
>
> ehrenhalber

The phrase **der Einfachheit halber** is just the expanded form with the exact same meaning. It's preferred if the noun is rather long or already an aggregate, and *die Einfachheit* is.